# config.Routes.MapHttpRoute getting overridden Web API 2.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httphandler

Why my AccessManagement route template not visible in MVC Web API 2.

```
// Web API routes
//config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

//Just exclude the users controllers from need to provide valid token, so they could authenticate
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Authentication",
    routeTemplate: "AccessManagement/",
    defaults: new { controller = "AccessManagement" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null,
    //Create and instance of TokenInspector setting the default inner handler
    handler: new TokenInspector() { 
        InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) 
    }
);
```

I need to protect all my routes having template `api/{controller}/{action}` by ensuring token is present in header and only one route is exposed without header which is `AccessManagement/`

Comment: The first route won't match anything, except for `www.whatever.com/AccessManagement`

Comment: Route is matching with `api/controller` instead of AccessManagement instead. However what I am looking for is, request should match both formats. Any solution

Comment: What route are you trying to match? AccessManagement/whatever? Then the template should be `AccessManagement/{*whatever}`

Comment: `http://localhost:49531/AccessManagement/Authenticate` failing with error 404, while `http://localhost:49531/api/AccessManagement/Authenticate` is hitting breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, your first route will only match the URL `"/AccessManagement"` and it won't accept anything else.

So, given the URL http://localhost:49531/AccessManagement/Authenticate and assuming your `AccessManagement` controller has an action named `Authenticate`, this route will match the URL:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Authentication",
    routeTemplate: "AccessManagement/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AccessManagement" }
);
```

Comment: This worked for me, everything is working now as desired. However I don't understand what was happening earlier. I understand URL template was not matching since I was passing action and action was not specified. Is there a way to view routing table on .NET? Also when should I use `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`